# Series of books about young pirate

Tags: story-identification, books, space, pirates

I cannot remember the name of a series of books I read when I was young (in 2003-2006). It was about a young boy, a pirate, who was traveling with his crew. There were a lot of planets. It was fun and a bit creepy sometimes. I remember big monsters and a quest. But there was a lot of books and I didn't finish them. I think the hero's name was Pip or something like that. They were books for teenagers.

Does anyone know the name of this series?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: You used the tag [tag:space].  I assume this is a science fiction.  Is it pirates in a space ship/rocket or something more fantastic like [Treasure Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treasure_Planet)?

Comment: Maybe Alan Dean Foster's [Pip & Flinx](https://www.goodreads.com/series/51810-pip-flinx) books.

Comment: ^_^ Pip being the minidrag, and Flinx the human, but good point, eshier.

Comment: Yes it was fantasty, like Treasure Planet :) Good idea eshier but I don't think it was those books. I don't remember a minidrag in the story. :/

Comment: Nobody can help me? :(

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you're thinking of *[Tales of Pirx the Pilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Pirx_the_Pilot)* by Stanisław Lem?

> The stories are set somewhere in the 21st or 22nd centuries, in a futuristic Occidental world (as opposed to a Communist Utopia where some of Lem's other novels take place) in which Mankind is starting to colonize the Solar System, has some settlements on the Moon and Mars, and is even beginning the exploration of the other solar systems.
>
> Pirx is a cadet, a pilot, and finally a captain of a merchant spaceship, and the stories relate his life and various things that happen to him during his travels between the Earth, Moon, and Mars.

While there were only two books, they each had several stories in them.

Comment: Thanks for the help but no, it was in several books (at least 5) and more fantastic than Tales of Pirx the Pilot.